# ¿Cómo mostrar un elemento HTML dependiendo de la URL con ng-show?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css3

Lo que quiero hacer con `ng-show` es que aparezca este template en una URL que tiene `id` `(/news/:id)`. Si hay una mejor forma de hacerlo, pues mejor.

```js
app.component('backButtonComponent', {
    template: '<a ng-show=" ? " id="back-button" ng-href="/news"></a>',
    controller: ['$scope','$location','$routeParams',function backButtonComponentCtrl ($scope,$location,$routeParams){
      // ?
    }]
  });
```

Estilos del template:

```css
#back-button {
  position: fixed;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: url("../svg/back.svg") no-repeat center center;
  background-size: 24px 24px;
  background-color: #3c3f41;
  z-index: 12!important;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 1px 18px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 3px 5px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); /* 6dp */
}
```

Comment: Porque no incluyes ese bloque de HTML en la ruta y ya? O es que es parte del layout de tu página?

Comment: @devconcept es un botón que tengo flotando en la parte inferior derecha de la página, específicamente lo tengo en el index.html, si lo incluyo en el template de la ruta en la que quiero que aparezca deja de flotar, ósea el `position: fixed;` por alguna razón deja de funcionar.

Comment: Creo que la solución correcta es arreglar el problema de estilo en logar de crear una solución compleja para un problema simple. Edita la pregunta y agrega el estilo correspondiente.

Comment: @devconcept eh agregado los estilos, pero no creo que el problema este en ellos. Creo que el problema está en que no se puede colocar un elemento flotante dentro de un template de las rutas de AngularJS. "creo" tampoco que sea experto en AngularJS lol.

Comment: Ya intentaste estilar el botón usando una clase en lugar de por id? el lugar de `#back-button` escribe `.back-button` y en tu `template` algo como `<a class="back-button" ng-href="/news"></a>`. Si por casualidad tienes otro botón idéntico que has olvidado en tu HTML te dejará de funcionar ya que en HTML es ilegal tener ids repetidos.

Comment: @devconcept Claro es el único estilo con id `#back-button`. También eh cambiado el id a una clase y sigue sucediendo lo mismo, no entiendo que sucede.

Comment: Porque usas `ng-show="?"`. No será esa la causa?

Comment: @devconcept no, solo puse ese "?" cómo pregunta de qué función debería de poner ahí.

Answer (score 0):

La solución es crear una `funcion` en el `controlador` que devuelva verdadero o falso segun el `url`...Debes usar `$location` y comparar el `url` con el que te conviene dentro de esa `funcion`....luego colocas el `ng-show="tuFuncion()"`

Comment: No entiendo muy bien cómo la función haría aparecer o desaparecer el template ¿Podrías darme un ejemplo por favor ?

Answer (score 0):

Puedieras hacer algo asi:

```
 app.run(['$rootScope', function ($rootScope){
        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState){
            $rootScope.UrlActive=toState.name;
        });
    }]);
```

y en tu html

```
<a ng-show="UrlActive=='miurl'?true:false" id="back-button" ng-href="/news"></a>
```

Comment: Lo eh implementado y no me funciona, solo se oculta y no se muestra al estar en la url.